# Replacing an element in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values that I grab from a form and store in each in an array. I want to check if these values are equal to the values I originally set, and if not I replace them with invalid. This is to prevent users from changing the values and allowing them to submit via some sort of web tools (i.e Chrome F12).

```
 foreach($hear_array as $val) 
 {
   $newval = "Invalid";
   if($val != "Value1" || $val != "Value2" || $val != "Value3" || $val != $_POST['select_other']) 
   {
        array_replace($hear_array, $newval);
    }           
 }
```

As for this piece of code it should detect if a value in the `$hear_array` is not equivalent to something I set as a value. I've also tried this as well:

```
array_replace($hear_array[$val], $newval);
```

Which didn't really seem to work either.

Comment: Why do you need a "replace" function?  You are already looping through the array.  Simply set the value based on the index of where you are.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I'm having trouble on how to do that. `$hear_array[$val] = $hear_array[$newval]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this (as suggested in my comment).  Add a pointer to track where you are in the array.  Then set your value at THAT index when you find what you want to change.

```
$arrayPointer = 0;

foreach($hear_array as $val) {
    $newval = "Invalid";
    if($val != "Value1" || $val != "Value2" || $val != "Value3" || $val != $_POST['select_other']) {
        $hear_array[$arrayPointer] = $newval);
    }
    $arrayPointer++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_search to obtain key and then replace value.

```
$key = array_search($needle, $hear_array);
if ($key !== false) {
    $hear_array[$key] = $newval;
}
```